# How to add more than one iOS projects into single repository in Github?

Tags: git, github

How to manage multiple iOS projects in single Git repository?

I've tried to create branches using following steps:

1. git clone repositoryUrl
2. git branch BranchName
3. git status
4. git checkout BranchName

but created branch is not showing in my repository. Or how to add multiple folders in single repo? Or any other way to add multiple projects into single repo?
Can anybody suggest something please?
Thanks.

Comment: Why didn't you just put them on different folders?

Comment: _but created branch is not showing in my repository_ -> did you make a git push?

Comment: So you are telling to create folder in my iOS project, and in that folder my i ve to put my another iOS projects and Push that folder right?

Comment: did you make a git push? – Yes @Leonardo Alves Machado

Comment: _Please_ don't do this. Branches aren't designed to hold entirely different code bases, and Git itself works best with one repository per project.

Comment: but my projects very small so i thought to put all my projects in one repo.

Comment: Size is irrelevant. Git repositories aren't designed with multiple project repositories in mind. It's possible to do this, but you'll be fighting against the tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know how to use git? If not learn first. Seems like you didn't push your code on new branch. Try git add - commit - push (Find these commands from [git docs](https://git-scm.com/documentation))

You can manage multiple projects in single git (not recommended)

1. Clone your git repo
2. Add you first project in master branch (commit + push)
3. Create another branch and delete all project files and directories (Do not delete .git)
4. Add second project files, and push

If you find using command-line is hard for you try tools like [tortoisegit](https://tortoisegit.org/) or [gitkraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/)